# How do I get the data of the child of the parent's child? Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The parent is Exam, the child of Exam is Question, and the child of Question is Choices

I wanted to display all questions of this certain exam (exam_id) with its corresponding choices.

### Exam Model

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Questions');
}
```

### Question Model

```
public function exams()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Exam', 'exam_id', 'exam_id');
}

public function choices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Choice');
}
```

### Choice Model

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Question', 'question_id', 'question_id');
}
```

### In Controller

```
$all = Exam::with(['questions','questions.choices'])->where('exam_id', $examID)->get();
```

I don't seem to get the desired result. It throws an error of Class 'App\Questions' not found. I just started laravel hope someone could help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one small misleading `$this->hasMany('App\Questions'` must be `$this->hasMany('App\Question')` in Exam Model

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}
```

I suggest you use this structure

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this all along. However, I'm not getting any returns from questions nor choices. The code I have in controller (stated above) only returns the exam data. Questions is blank/empty even if I have questions inside this certain exam. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: For this time I see only that part. You must be add you db structure for I can see more detailed

Comment: Also show `Exam::with(['questions'])->where('exam_id', $examID)->get();`

Comment: Also you can try this `public function exams()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question', 'exam_id', 'exam_id');
}`

Comment: Oh now I get it. I have to put the primary and the foreign key along `return $this->hasMany`. Thank you so much @Davit very much appreciated.